# Do an inequality and multiple "array-contains", or array-contains-like filters

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run a query with an inequality and multiple `array-contains`.

For simplicity, I simplified the data structure with imaginary data. Let's say in a collection called `grocerie_packages` I have many documents. I want to be able to proved searches based on the name of the package, the price of the package and the vegetables and fruits it contains. The current data structure is the following:

```
{
    price: 10,
    contained_fruits: ["apple", "pear", "grape"],
    contained_vegetables: ["tomato", "cucumber", "carrot"],
    package_name: ["f", "fa", "fam", "fami", "famil", "family", "family_", "family_s", "family_si", "family_siz", "family_size"]
}
```

At first, I used the following code to query based on the name:

```
.where("package_name", ">=", searchString)
.where("package_name", "<=", searchString + "\uf8ff");
```

But later, when I added the functionality of querying by price I ran into the issue of:

> Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) must be on the same field.

I solved it by creating an array of the substrings of `package_name`. The code I used was something like this:

```
  .where("package_name", "array-contains", package_name_intput)
  .where("price", "<", max_price);
```

The problem I'm having is that now, since I did one `array-contains` to the query I can't query based on the contained vegetables and fruits. I don't want to sort on the client, since there are cases when I would return potentially thousands of items more than needed. I also can't combine the three array into one, because I only want to return a document if it matches all criteria of the query. For instance in a query where someone asks for `apple` and `carrot` I only want to return documents which contains both. If it was one array it would  return the document even if only one item is found in the package. I only need to provide one item (like `apple`) search per vegetables and fruits.

What is the best way for me to run a query like this? I'm trying to find a solution where I don't fill the document with many-many flags just for querying porpuses. For instance:

```
{
   flags: ["apple_tomato_f", "apple_tomato_fa", "apple_tomato_fam", ] //and so on
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching the inequality part of the query, by instead of letting the user give a specific **price** I only allow users to choose a **price range**, for instance:

Instead of setting the max price to `$10`, they can choose a range like `$5-$10`.

In production the solution is a little more complex, but for simplification this is the core idea.

So with the inequality and `composite index` problem out of the way, it was fairly simple to query with a new data structure. The new data structure:

```
{
    price: "$5-$10",
    contained_fruits: {
      peach: true,
      melon: true,
      cherry: true
    },
    contained_vegetables: {
        cucumber: true,
        tomato: true,
    },
    package_name: {
      b: true,
      bi: true,
      big: true, 
      big_: true,
      big_s: true,
      big_si: true,
      big_siz: true,
      big_size: true,
        
    }
}
```

Firebase lets multiple equality based queries, so this...:

```
.where("price", "==", price_input)
.where(`package_name.${package_name_intput}`, "==", true)
.where(`contained_vegetables.${vegetable_input}`, "==", true)
.where(`contained_fruits.${fruit_input}`, "==", true)
```

...works and is completely fine. A nice advantage of this is that I can let users search for multiple fruit and vegetable items per query, and I can manage the price based query fairly easily, although not as originally desired. I also don't have to bother with `composite indexes`, which is also nice.

That being said, if someone comes up with a viable solution to my original problem they are going to get *bounty* awarded.

Hope this helps, have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

**Let me preface this by saying...**

I just want to add that I wouldn't do this in a real project. Instead I would create an API on Cloud Run that performs multiple queries, structures the data, caches it temporarily and returns the results in whatever form I want.

However for the sake of flexing our pickled brains, here's how I would accomplish this with the following requirements:

1. Must query Firestore directly.
2. Only one query.
3. No client-side sorting.

**Big brain time**

First rethink your database structure.  To accomplish all of this in a single query you need to store your data so that you can use all available single-use operators.  To do that, store all of your fruits and vegetables as `{[key: string]: boolean}` like this:

```
{"grocerie_packages": {
        "abc1": {
            "price": 10,
            "tomato": true,
            "package_name": ["s", "si", "sin", "sing", "singl", "single", "single_s", "single_si", "single_siz", "single_size"]
        },
        "abc2": {
            "price": 20,
            "cucumber": true,
            "tomato": true,
            "package_name": ["f", "fa", "fam", "fami", "famil", "family", "family_", "family_s", "family_si", "family_siz", "family_size"]
        },
        "abc3": {
            "price": 30,
            "package_name": ["s", "si", "sin", "sing", "singl", "single", "single_s", "single_si", "single_siz", "single_size"]
        },
        "abc4": {
            "price": 40,
            "apple": true,
            "tomato": true,
            "package_name": ["f", "fa", "fam", "fami", "famil", "family", "family_", "family_s", "family_si", "family_siz", "family_size"]
        }
    }
}
```

That makes all of the following queries possible:

**Package name contains "fam", has tomatoes and the price is < 40**

```
    db.collection('grocerie_packages')
        .where('tomato', '==', true)
        .where('package_name', 'array-contains', 'fam')
        .where('price', '<', 40).get()
        .then((snap) => console.log("Results:", snap.docs.map(s => s.id).join(',')));
```

`Results: abc2`

**Package name contains "fam", has tomatoes and the price is < 100**

```
    db.collection('grocerie_packages')
        .where('tomato', '==', true)
        .where('package_name', 'array-contains', 'fam')
        .where('price', '<', 100).get()
        .then((snap) => console.log("Results:", snap.docs.map(s => s.id).join(',')));
```

`Results: abc2,abc4`

**Package has cucumbers and costs > 10**

```
    db.collection('grocerie_packages')
        .where('cucumber', '==', true)
        .where('price', '>', 10).get()
        .then((snap) => console.log("Results:", snap.docs.map(s => s.id).join(',')));
```

`Results: abc2`

**Package name contains "sing", has tomatoes, cucumbers and apples and the price is > 100**

```
    db.collection('grocerie_packages')
        .where('tomato', '==', true)
        .where('cucumber', '==', true)
        .where('apple', '==', true)
        .where('package_name', 'array-contains', 'sing')
        .where('price', '>', 100).get()
        .then((snap) => console.log("Results:", snap.docs.map(s => s.id).join(',')));
```

`Results:`

Comment: I have thought of this:) The only problem, that in a data structure like this I would need to create a `composite index` for every field because of the inequality based search... which besides being a pain in the bum, I can only create so many of them (200). And what if the seller adds a new, previously not indexed vegetable? Well queries would have to wait until I create the appropriate index for them.

Comment: You're trying to get SQL querying flexibility from a NoSQL database so the above is the only solution that meets all of your requirements.  When a seller adds a new vegetable you'd need to create the new index immediately and have limited sorting options.  The only other options would be to do client-side sorting or add Algolia or ElasticCache and use that to perform your searches but I didn't mention it because those aren't answers to your original question.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to:) I'm searching for workarounds, or solutions that real world apps would use.

Comment: Use any of the alternatives that I posted above, either multiple queries with client-side sorting or use Algolia/ElasticSearch.  Those are how this would be accomplished in a real project.  The above answer is the only way to accomplish this with a single query and no client-side sorting on Firestore.

Comment: Well let's see if someone can come up with something real clever or some with some out of box idea. I couldn't and that's why I'm offering a bounty :-)

Comment: @BudaÖrs What you are looking for is a solution that provides elements of full text search which as well know is a problem in itself which datastores built around that problem (elasticsearch, solr etc) and then the regular SQL style querying capability which firestore offers but with some limitations. Given these two things clearly you have run into limitations of the firebase platform.  I have spent fair amount of time working with firestore, solr and regular databases like mysql. I think the solution offered by Brian is the best option while staying with the mentioned constraints.

Comment: At best you can look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search and combine it with something that Brain has already mentioned

Comment: Thank you! I will defenetly look into it:)

Answer (score -1):

is it really impossible with your query to use the keyword OR in your queries?

for your multiple contains, use 'tomato' in fruit or 'tomato' in vegetables?
A clause like this should handle both of your cases

It sounds to me like your problem really is that of boolean logic.

Comment: Can you detail this a little bit more? And with some code examples?